# error during build using sandcastle help builder with visual studio 2010 .NET 4.0 project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, sandcastle

I was using sandcastle to generate help for my project in visual studio 2008. When i change my project to visual studio 2010 and change the project .NET version to .NET 4.0 i got this problem with Sandcastel. I can't understand why sandcastel is using C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\MSBuild.exe
and not 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0\MSBuild.exe 
thinking that i specified as framework version the v4.0.30319

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue?? Where to change the path of the msbuild.exe or some other solution ???

```
Generating reflection information...
[C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\MSBuild.exe]
GenerateRefInfo:
  MrefBuilder (v2.4.10520.1)
  Copyright c Microsoft 2006
  Info: Loaded 1 assemblies for reflection and 0 dependency assemblies.
MREFBUILDER : error : Unresolved assembly reference: System.Windows.Forms (System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089) required by WLAEDInt

Last step completed in 00:00:01.2731

-------------------------------

SHFB: Error BE0043: Unexpected error detected in last build step.  See output above for details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem today, and this post helped me resolve it: http://shfb.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=214594

Solution summary:

Step 1: 
Ensure you've got the latest Sandcastle patches, especially for VS2010, available at: sandcastlestyles.codeplex.com. As of today, it is 'Sandcastle May 2008 Patch Rev 3 '.

Step 2:
Add another supportedRuntime element to the 'MRefBuilder.exe.config' file that utilizes the RTM version of .NET 4.0:

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/> <!-- 4.0 RTM -->
```

I still had the error after step 1, then step 2 finally fixed it.

Comment: where is this config file?

Comment: @EricSchneider: file `MRefBuilder.config` gets installed along with all the Sandcastle files, deployed to the path you installed Sandcastle onto your local workstation.  It is the config file for assembly `MRefBuilder.exe`.   I don't have it installed anymore, so can't recommend a default path.
I did examine latest release (https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB/releases/tag/v2021.4.9.0), and verified the MSI install package still contains file `MRefBuilder.config` .

Answer (score 2):

The current version of Sandcastle does not support .NET 4 without some config hackery. There is [a new version](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=209712) that should be available quite soon, expected to support .NET 4 out of the box.

Edit: the [latest Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/releases/view/47665) is available now; perhaps that will solve your issue, since it includes .NET 4 support.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem with the latest version of the *Sandcastle Help File Builder v1.9.1.0* with regards to the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting` library.

I resolved it by copying the referenced `UITest` assemblies (buried in the Visual Studio directory) to the directory containing the documentation source.  Then bingo the build worked for the *Sandcastle Help File Builder*.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by a bad xml comment code item.

```
   ''' <code language="cs"  title="Example #1" source="MISSING SOURCE FILE"/>
   ''' <code language="vbnet"  title="Example #2" source="MISSING SOURCE FILE"/>
```

Error from **LastBuild.log**:

```
BuildAssembler : error : CodeBlockComponent: [T:FrozenElephant.Symbiotic.DatabaseTypesFactory] Unable to load source file &#39;G:\Dev\FrozenElephant\SymbioticORM\SymbioticUniversalTests\UniversalTestProject_CS\ExampleUnitTests\AbstractFactoryTests.cs&#39;.  Error: Could not find file &#39;G:\Dev\FrozenElephant\SymbioticORM\SymbioticUniversalTests\UniversalTestProject_CS\ExampleUnitTests\AbstractFactoryTests.cs&#39;. [G:\Dev\FrozenElephant\SymbioticORM\Symbiotic.Docs\Help\Working\BuildTopics.proj]
```